# What is 'this' inside the scope of the promise then() or catch()?

Tags: javascript, this

I want to clarify the 'this' within a promise `then()` or `catch()` function scope. Ex:

```js
//this= 1     
this.promiseFunction("id1").then(
                (response) => {
                     //this = 2 
                     //what is 'this' here ?
                }).catch(() => {
                     //this = 3
                     //what is 'this' here ?
                });
```

Is 'this' referred by 1 and 2 are equal? How does that happen?

Comment: yes - because arrow functions work like that - take on the `this` of the enclosing scope (I think that's how it's worded) - from the docs *An arrow function does not create its own this context, so this has its original meaning from the enclosing context.*

Comment: @JaromandaX—which "docs"?

Comment: In this specific case, you need to learn about arrow functions. In general, promise methods (`then`, `catch`) don't set any `this` context when they invoke the callback, so it'll be `undefined` in a normal `function` (and the global object in a sloppy mode one).

Comment: From EMCA-262: "*An ArrowFunction does not define local bindings for arguments, super, this, or new.target. Any reference to arguments, super, this, or new.target within an ArrowFunction must resolve to a binding in a lexically enclosing environment. Typically this will be the Function Environment of an immediately enclosing function.*" In other words, an arrow function uses the *this* of its enclosing execution context.

Comment: this.promiseFunction("id1").then(function myFunction(ddd) {
                 //this = 3  
                 // this here ?
                }
            )
This is not an arrow function now.
So 'this' here(3) should be different to this(1) ?